# nestjs+swagger fileupload with additional dto question

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I've posted before, but my question has not been resolved, so I've edited the post and re-posted it.

```js
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'upload' })
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiBody({ type: AddTestDto })
@Post('test')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor(
      [
        { name: 'test1', maxCount: 5 },
        { name: 'test2', maxCount: 5 },
      ],
      {
        storage: multerS3({
          s3: s3,
          bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          acl: 'public-read',
          key: function (request, file, cb) {
            cb(
              null,
              `test/${file.fieldname}/${uuid()}_${
                file.originalname
              }`,
            );
          },
        }),
        fileFilter: extensionHelper,
      },
    ),
  )
  async uploadTest(
    @Body() body: AddTestDto,
    @UploadedFiles() file?: Express.MulterS3.File[],
  ) {
     console.log(file);
     console.log(body.additionalDto);
     console.log(body.additionalDto[0]);
   }
```

```js
export class AddTestDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'file',
    name: 'test1',
    properties: {
      file: {
        type: 'string',
        format: 'binary',
      },
    },
    isArray: true,
  })
  @IsOptional()
  test1: any[];

  @ApiProperty({
    name: 'test2',
    type: 'file',
    properties: {
      file: {
        type: 'string',
        format: 'binary',
      },
    },
    isArray: true,
  })
  @IsOptional()
  test2: any[];

  @ApiProperty({
    type: AddDto,
    isArray: true,
  })
  @Type(() => AddDto)
  @IsOptional()
  additionalDto: AddDto[];
}
```

The code is written as above, and additionalDto includes string and number.
Below is the swagger screen.

[swagger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQVTM.png)

And, I send the data as above and check the console.log in the controller, the file looks fine.

And in the second console.log, the data is shown as an array.

However, the last console.log is typeof string and only one '[' character is displayed.

I want to receive file array and dto array at the same time through apibody.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seem like a problem of Swagger. At Content type : *multipart/form-data*, it will send array of object like

```
{
 key1 : "value1",
 key2 : "value2"
},
{
 key1 : "value1-1",
 key2 : "value2-1"
},
```

that is missing *square bracket* at begin and end of string. Nest will auto transform object string to json, but it can not understand above string, because it is not validated type of json. So, we need manual transform it with little custom :

```
  @ApiProperty({
    type: AddDto,
    isArray: true,
  })
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    const parsedObj = JSON.parse(`[${value}]`);
    return parsedObj;
  })
  @Type(() => AddDto)
  @IsOptional()
  additionalDto: AddDto[];
```